# React, Graphql - how to pass variable to mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm trying create a simple CRUD app using Graphql in React.

I have the Create and Read but I'm really struggling with the delete.

I have the backend all set up and everything works in the Playground.

In the Playground I can us the delete mutation like

```
mutation{
    deleteRecipe(_id: "5e22e40f9f3478160a31555a"){
      _id
      name
    }
}
```

and get the response

```
{
  "data": {
    "deleteRecipe": {
      "_id": "5e22e40f9f3478160a31555a",
      "name": "test 13"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm having big problems getting this mutation working in React (In React the Create and Read are wotking)

server side

schema.js

```
exports.typeDefs = `

  type Recipe{
    _id: String
    name: String
    description: String
  }

  type Query{
    recipe:[Recipe]
  }

  type Mutation{
    addRecipe(name: String!, description: String):Recipe,
    deleteRecipe(_id: String!):Recipe
  }

`
```

resolvers.js

```
exports.resolvers = {

  Query: {
    recipe: async (obj, args, { Recipe }, info) => {
      const allRecipes = await Recipe.find()
      return allRecipes
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    addRecipe: async (obj, { name, description }, { Recipe }, info) => {
      const newRecipe = await new Recipe({
        name,
        description
      }).save()
      return newRecipe
    },
    deleteRecipe: async (obj, { _id }, { Recipe }, info) => {
      const delRecipe = await Recipe.findByIdAndRemove({ _id })
      return delRecipe
    }
  }
}
```

client side

queries/index.tsx

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const GET_ALL_RECIPES = gql`
  query RecipeData{
    recipe{
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`

export const ADD_RECIPE = gql`
  mutation addRecipe($name: String!, $description:String){
    addRecipe(name: $name, description: $description){
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`

export const DELETE_RECIPE = gql`
  mutation deleteRecipe($id: String!){
    deleteRecipe(_id: $id){
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { RecipeData } from '../generated/RecipeData';
import { GET_ALL_RECIPES, ADD_RECIPE, DELETE_RECIPE } from '../queries';
import { useQuery, useMutation } from 'react-apollo-hooks';


const App: React.FC = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('')
  const [description, setDes] = useState<string>('')
  const [] = useState<string>('')

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   deleteRecipe()
  // }, [recipeId])

  const handleNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleDesChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setDes(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    createRecipe()
  };

  const [deleteRecipe] = useMutation(DELETE_RECIPE)

  const handelDelete = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const delID = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id")
    deleteRecipe({ variables: { _id: delID }, refetchQueries: ['RecipeData'] });
  }

  // const [deleteRecipe, {data}] = useMutation(DELETE_RECIPE, {
  //   variables: { _id:  }, refetchQueries: ['RecipeData']
  // })

  const [createRecipe, { error }] = useMutation(ADD_RECIPE, {
    variables: { name, description }, refetchQueries: ['RecipeData']
  })
  if (error) {
    console.error('erroring : ', error)
  }

  const { data, loading } = useQuery<RecipeData | null>(GET_ALL_RECIPES, {
    suspend: false
  })

  if (loading || !data) return <div>Loading</div>

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Graphql</h1>
      <ul>
        {
          data.recipe !== null && data.recipe.map((recipe) => (
            <li key={recipe._id} data-id={recipe._id}>
              {recipe.name}
              <button onClick={handelDelete}>X</button>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>

      <form>
        <div>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={handleNameChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Description</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={description}
            onChange={handleDesChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Recipe</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the Network tab I'm getting the error

```
"Variable "$id" of required type "String!" was not provided.",…
```

I'm assuming I'm not passing the id value to the deleteRecipe

How can I pass the id to deleteRecipe here

```
  const [deleteRecipe] = useMutation(DELETE_RECIPE)

  const handelDelete = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const delID = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id")
    deleteRecipe({ variables: { _id: delID }, refetchQueries: ['RecipeData'] });
  }
```

Comment: What's the name of your variable? What's the name in the `variables` object you're passing to `deleteRecipe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is `id`

```
{ variables: { id: delID }
```